# UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp \ UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown doesn't support both variants of the portrait orientation?

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm using the UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp \ UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown transitions to flip between view controllers.

Problem is when I try to support the upsidedown portrait orientation , these lovely curl transitions still think they are in normal portrait orientation, thus the curlup goes from top to bottom and the curldown goes from bottom to top.

It seems like these transitions doesnt care about the device orientation and neither the interface orientation, so - is there a way to force them to flip?

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a rotated coordinate system. See the `transform` property of UIView.